# IOS: Pause background music from ipod

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I use openAL and AVAudio to play soundeffects in my game. The users are allowed to listen to music from other source while playing (AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)

During the game, the soundeffects blends together smoothly with the background music.

However, after a game completes, I want to play my own little soundtrack, which won't sound good if the user is listning to some other music.

If I change

```
AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient
```

to

```
AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
```

I can turn of the ipod music.

However, is there anyway I can resume the background music when switching back to AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient after my own music track has finished?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this?

```
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player
            successfully: (BOOL) flag {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient
            error:nil];
}
```

in the AVAudioPlayer delegate.